# Jquery analytics for wordpress to track each event/click

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-analytics

I am trying to add a jquery plugin that will enable google analytics to track every event on the site. anyone has an idea how to do that?

if you want to take a look this is the url blog.dearcomms.com

Comment: All I know is that site was awfully slow on my netbook... is that what you are trying to replicate?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a [plugin for GA](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/) though I'm not sure what all it offers.  But anyways, there is no generic code that will automatically "track every event on the site". Events are arbitrary, unique to your site and needs.  You must define the events on your site that you want to track and then write custom code for it.

Comment: hi thanks will take a look at that - is there anyway to contact you via email?